# filtrar numero dentro de um texto (.txt ou .csv) com python

Tags: python, pandas, arquivo, txt

Sou novo no Python e não estou conseguindo encontrar uma forma de buscar um número dentro de um .txt. Basicamente, quero buscar um número dentro de um arquivo de texto independente de como ele esteja escrito, por exemplo o CPF, pode ser escrito com pontuação ou sem. (Ex. de CPF: 123.123.123-12, 12312312312 ou 123123123-12)

quero que ele retorne apenas os números do CPF para preencher cadastro.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Basicamente, quero buscar um número dentro de um arquivo de texto independente de como ele esteja escrito, por exemplo o CPF, pode ser escrito com pontuação ou sem. (123.123.123-12, 12312312312 ou 123123123-12)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas você pode usar expressões regulares para buscar ou extrair padrões de string.

```py
import re

txt = "seu texto com cpf"
x01 = re.search(r"^[0-9]{11}$", txt)
x01 = re.search(r"^[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{2}$", txt)
```

Comment: Diego, muito obrigado!
Consegui encontrar o CPF, consegue me dizer se tem alguma forma de eu formatar o retorno para uma string?

ele retorna: <re.Match object; span=(14, 25), match='50050050050'>

eu consigo retornar apenas '50050050050'?

Comment: Tente algo como: found = re.search('AAA (.+?) ZZZ', str).group(1)